# How to install scala kernel for hydrogen?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor, hydrogen

I'm looking at: https://nteract.io/kernels it's saying how to install python kernels for hydrogen:

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

but which `python -m pip install [scala kernel?]` command should I use to install the scala kernel? or is it a whole other process? where is the documentation or step by step on how to install hydrogen with scala kernel and working with it?